# Can I make the Fujiflm X-T10's rear LCD stay off except when using the menu?

Tags: camera-settings, fujifilm, rear-lcd

The Fujifilm X-T10 has several different [viewfinder modes](http://fujifilm-dsc.com/en/manual/x-t10/parts/button_view/index.html). I'm coming from a mid-range DSLR and am used to using the top LCD for at-a-glance info and the rear LCD only for menu setup. I want something basically similar here, with the rear LCD only turning on when I hit the menu button (or the `Q` quick-menu button).

The modes are:

- *Eye sensor*: Automatic display selection using eye sensor
- *EVF only*: Viewfinder only
- *LCD only*: [Rear] LCD monitor only
- *EVF only + eye sensor* : Viewfinder only; eye sensor turns display on or off

Basically, I want *EVF only + eye sensor*, except when I push the menu button, at which point I want it to switch to *Eye sensor*. If you have it on *EVF only*, it does exactly this for the **playback** button — the rear LCD shows your images for review or even the playback menu, but it'll switch to the EVF if you put the camera to your eye.

Is there a way to get this behavior in shooting mode?

I'm afraid that the answer is "sorry, it can't do this", but the Fujifilm configuration interface is a little alien to me and I keep finding options tucked where I don't expect them.

Comment: Drives a lot of X100T owners nuts, too: http://www.fujix-forum.com/index.php/topic/31721-x100t-use-ovf-but-menu-show-up-on-lcd/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, **you can't — there's no option for this**. However, if you use the *EVF only + eye sensor* mode, and then press the `DISP` button while looking at the rear screen, it will a cycle between:

- no-distraction live view (only showing the scene)
- live view with shooting info (aperture, ISO, focus mode, etc.,  as configured in the settings menu)
- a black and white screen showing *just* the shooting info

So, as a work-around, you can use this last mode. It's not *off*, but I find it less annoying. (The histogram is still live, so I doubt it saves power — oh well.)

Note that if you look through the finder and press `DISP`, it will change the viewfinder display separately, between "clean" and "info overlay" modes.